# Codeigniter REST CSV import to mysql

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-2

I want to post csv file on my controller using API.I'm using Codeigniter REST Library by phil sturgeon. How to implement on the client side the importing of CSV to my REST Server.I just want to ask because I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: You are not enough clear with the question. Codeigniter REST is almost same as normal Codeigniter but the difference is just calling the method and response.

In normal codeigniter we calls `controller/function` where in REST it must be `resource/{resource_id}/child_resource/{child_resource_id}`.

i don't thing there will be any problem for sending the headers as `.xls` file

Comment: clealy and in simple words tell us what you want

Comment: @raheelshan I want to post csv file on my controller using client side API by jquery.post and extract the csv file data and import to mysql.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do this. I don't know what people do but i use this

This is my csv reader library, Save this in libraries folder as csvreader.php.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CSVReader {

    var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
    var $separator  =   ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure  =   '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

    var $max_row_size   =   4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath) 
    {
        $file           =   fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields   =   fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values        =   explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

        $content            =   array();
        $keys           =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   1;
        while(($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) 
        {
            if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
                $values         =   explode(',',$row[0]);
                if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                    $arr            =   array();
                    $new_values =   array();
                    $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                    for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                        if($keys[$j]    !=  ""){
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                        }
                    }
                    $content[$i]    =   $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $content;
    }

    function escape_string($data)
    {
        $result =   array();
        foreach($data as $row){
            $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
        }
        return $result;
    }   
}
?>
```

And controller method

```
function readExcel()
{
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file('Test.csv');//path to csv file

        $data['csvData'] =  $result;
        $this->load->view('view_csv', $data);  
}
```

And this is view

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td width = "10%">ID</td>
            <td width = "20%">NAME</td>
            <td width = "20%">SHORT DESCRIPTION</td>
            <td width = "30%">LONG DESCRIPTION</td>
            <td width = "10%">STATUS</td>
            <td width = "10%">PARENTID</td>
    </tr>

            <?php foreach($csvData as $field){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $field['id']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['shortdesc']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['longdesc']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['status']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['parentid']?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
</table>
```

Note : This will only read a file which exists on server. If the file is needed to be uploaded use [File Upload Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) to upload file and save it to some location on your server then give the path of located file in `parse_file` method. And everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try I just need the data to extract and pass it to the model.

Comment: you can pass the returned array to model

Comment: how if my csv fields without $enclosure '"'? it return error if i put $enclosure = '';

Comment: @ChrisSuen can you post an example so i can test

Comment: @raheelshan how should be the csv file to be able to use this exact same view you use in this example? I used this exact same example but I still couldn't display the data of a CSV file I prepared here. :( (it's been a while I don't code in php and I'm trying to get back to it again)

Comment: Well @Periback you are supposed to create view yourself according to the sequence of fields in csv. If you need different sequence you must rearrange the array. And the above sample code works fine. You might be making mistake somewhere. Can you tell what problem you are facing in detail?

Comment: sure, I can @raheelshan. I'm trying to read 5 txt files sequentially and they're like csv files, but the separator is semicolon and they have different number of columns. I'm using your approach to read the file and it's working good to do this, but I'm still a bit confused with the array structure, since there's been a while I dont code in PHP.

Comment: @raheelshan, I did it! now I'm just trying to figure out a way to print the data..

Comment: try this.. perfect

'' http://www.sourcecodester.com/download-code?nid=6477&title=How+to+Import+CSV+Data+in+Codeigniter&uri=%2Fphp%2F6477%2Fhow-import-csv-data-codeigniter.html''

Comment: Nice, This answer will help me but i want to know in which table i need to import CSV file? I need a code to import CSV file in table.

Comment: its up to your own requirements. You will have a collection on which you can loop through and run insert query in database