# How display the contents of a CSV file in the browser using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select a file and display its contents as it is in the browser. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('your_file_name.csv');` :P

Comment: can i then use that displayed data for further processing like if i have to check if a particular field in the file is present in the database or not?

Comment: Thank you that works :) and i want to have a Big text box in which i can copy the contents of a CSV file as it is is this possile?

Comment: `echo '<textarea style="width:100%;height:100%;">'.file_get_contents('your_file_name.csv').'</textarea>';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library that reads contents of csv file and displays it as table. It is basically a class. if you have object oriented concepts you can do with it.
View my answer

[Codeigniter REST CSV import to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125)