# CSV Import Library for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, csv, codeigniter-2, helper, xls

Need to implement csv or xls import into Application created using CodeIgniter. Is there any library for this? Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do this. I don't know what people do but i use this

This is my csv reader library

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CSVReader {

    var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
    var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

    var $max_row_size = 4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

        $content    =   array();
        $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   1;
        while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {            
            if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
                $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);
                if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                    $arr    =   array();
                    $new_values =   array();
                    $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                    for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                        if($keys[$j] != ""){
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                        }
                    }

                    $content[$i]=   $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $content;
    }

    function escape_string($data){
        $result =   array();
        foreach($data as $row){
            $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
        }
        return $result;
    }   
}
?>
```

And controller method

```
function readExcel()
{
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file('Test.csv');

        $data['csvData'] =  $result;
        $this->load->view('view_csv', $data);  
}
```

And this is view

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td width = "10%">ID</td>
            <td width = "20%">NAME</td>
            <td width = "20%">SHORT DESCRIPTION</td>
            <td width = "30%">LONG DESCRIPTION</td>
            <td width = "10%">STATUS</td>
            <td width = "10%">PARENTID</td>
    </tr>

            <?php foreach($csvData as $field){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $field['id']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['shortdesc']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['longdesc']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['status']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $field['parentid']?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
</table>
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125)

Comment: Thx Raheel, did you implement this to input csv to database also?

Comment: yes just pass the `$result` to database table or form an array according to your requirements.

Comment: Still working great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MuhammadRaheel you assign this line  $this->csvreader->parse_file('Test.csv'); the csv file where i should have in computer i have tired i got an error like this Call to a member function parse_file() on null and another error is Message: Undefined property: Csv_import::$CsvReader

Comment: @Jack it clearly says it is null. You should provide valid path. For second issue are you sure you have loaded library properly.

Comment: @MuhammadRaheel this does not work to read csv file with 150000 rows. How can I read a big file ?

Comment: @piya could be a problem with your memory. Try increasing memory through php.ini

Answer (score 5):

This is an improved version of raheel shan's accepted answer - I edited his answer but my edit was rejected, however it is an important change...

When parsing each data row, it is not wise to use `explode()` on the comma as this does not handle quote-encased strings that contain commas. Explode breaks those strings into substrings and gives extra array elements in `$values`, so this check fails:

```
if (count($keys) == count($values)) {
```

Instead, PHP has a purpose-built method to handle this; [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). I have updated the original answer code accordingly.

The CSV Reader library:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CSVReader {

    var $fields;/** columns names retrieved after parsing */
    var $separator = ';';/** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure = '"';/** enclosure used to decorate each field */
    var $max_row_size = 4096;/** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys = str_getcsv($this->fields[0]);

        $i = 1;
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false) {
            if ($row != null) { // skip empty lines
                $values = str_getcsv($row[0]);
                if (count($keys) == count($values)) {
                    $arr = array();
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
                        if ($keys[$j] != "") {
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] = $values[$j];
                        }
                    }

                    $content[$i] = $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $content;
    }

}
?>
```

Controller method:

```
function readExcel() {
    $this->load->library('csvreader');
    $result = $this->csvreader->parse_file('Test.csv');
    $data['csvData'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('view_csv', $data);
}
```

And this is the view:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">ID</td>
        <td width="20%">NAME</td>
        <td width="20%">SHORT DESCRIPTION</td>
        <td width="30%">LONG DESCRIPTION</td>
        <td width="10%">STATUS</td>
        <td width="10%">PARENTID</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($csvData as $field) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $field['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $field['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $field['shortdesc'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $field['longdesc'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $field['status'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $field['parentid'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well don't mind me, I just modified ajmedway's library to include delimiters just in case you wanted to get data from lets say TSV or pipes delimited files. If you want plain old CSV his is just fine.

```
class CSVReader {

var $fields;/** columns names retrieved after parsing */
var $separator = ';';/** separator used to explode each line */
var $enclosure = '"';/** enclosure used to decorate each field */
var $max_row_size = 4096;/** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

function parse_file($p_Filepath, $delimiter = FALSE ) {

    $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
    $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
    if ($delimiter==FALSE)
    {
    $keys = str_getcsv($this->fields[0]);

    $i = 1;
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false) {
        if ($row != null) { // skip empty lines
            $values = str_getcsv($row[0]);
            if (count($keys) == count($values)) {
                $arr = array();
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
                    if ($keys[$j] != "") {
                        $arr[$keys[$j]] = $values[$j];
                    }
                }

                $content[$i] = $arr;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    else{
        $keys = str_getcsv($this->fields[0],$delimiter);

        $i = 1;
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false) {
            if ($row != null) { // skip empty lines
                $values = str_getcsv($row[0],$delimiter);
                if (count($keys) == count($values)) {
                    $arr = array();
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
                        if ($keys[$j] != "") {
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] = $values[$j];
                        }
                    }

                    $content[$i] = $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $content;
}}?>
```

Comment: This is wrong if ($delimiter=FALSE) as you are setting $delimiter to FALSE and not checking it's status. It should be if ($delimiter == FALSE)

Comment: whoops! Sorry. Rookie mistake. Thanks @Johnish. I will correct it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version for empty lines and extra spaces and tabs...

```
class CSVReader {

    function csv_to_array($Filepath)
    {
        //Get csv file content
        $csvData = file_get_contents($Filepath);
        
        //Remove empty lines
        $csvData = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\r\n", $csvData);
       
        //String convert in array formate and remove double quote(")
        $array = array();
        $array = $this->escape_string(preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $csvData));
        $new_content_in_array = array();
        if($array)
        {
            //Get array key
            $array_keys = array();
            $array_keys = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(';',$array[0])));
            
            //Get array value
            $array_values = array();
            for ($i=1;$i<count($array);$i++)
            {
                if($array[$i])
                {
                    $array_values[] = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(';',$array[$i])));
                }
            }
            
            //Convert in associative array
            if($array_keys && $array_values)
            {
                $assoc_array = array();
                foreach ($array_values as $ky => $val)
                {           
                    for($j=0;$j<count($array_keys);$j++){
                        if($array_keys[$j] != "" && $val[$j] != "" && (count($array_keys) == count($val)))
                        {
                            $assoc_array[$array_keys[$j]] = $val[$j];
                        }
                    }
                    $new_content_in_array[] = $assoc_array;
                }
            }
        }
        return $new_content_in_array;
    }
    
    function escape_string($data){
        $result =   array();
        foreach($data as $row){
            $result[]   = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "", str_replace('"', '',$row));
        }
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Call in controller:

```
$this->load->library('csvreader');
$import_csv_data = $this->csvreader->csv_to_array($path);
print_r($import_csv_data );
exit;
```