# How do I insert data from a CSV file into my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload my txt file into my database but I don't think anything happens. I checked my database in phpmyadmin but nothing was inserted. How do I load and insert my data into mysql database?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("database", $conn);

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $uploadtxt = "nyccrash.txt";

    $handle= fopen($uploadtxt, "r");

    // error checking.
    if($handle === false) {
   die("Error opening $uploadtxt");
}


    while($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",") !== false) { 

    $crash_year = $fileop[0];
    $accident_type = $fileop[1];
    $collision_type = $fileop[2];
    $weather_condition = $fileop[3];
    $light_condition = $fileop[4];
    $x_coordinate = $fileop[5];
    $y_coordinate = $fileop[6];


    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nyccrash (crash_year, accident_type, collision_type, weather_condition, light_condition, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) VALUES ($crash_year, $accident_type, $collision_type, $weather_condition, $light_condition, $x_coordinate, $y_coordinate)"); 

    } }
```

?>

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> NYC Crash Data </title> 
<link ref="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="../style/style.css" /> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="mainWrapper"> 

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <br/> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
    </form> 

</div>
```

Comment: are you connecting to the database anywhere in your code?

Comment: You should add error handling and output or log the result of `mysql_error()` to figure out what doesn't work properly. Also...please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. It's deprecated and will at some point be removed from PHP. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead.

Comment: You`ve uploaded file incorrectly. Check `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`  and read about correct [uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: @martincarlin87, Yeah I've connected to my database. For some reason, Stack overflow doesn't want to show that part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is text data then you forgot `'` around data

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nyccrash (crash_year, accident_type, 
collision_type, weather_condition, light_condition, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) 
VALUES ('$crash_year', '$accident_type', '$collision_type', 
'$weather_condition', '$light_condition', '$x_coordinate', '$y_coordinate')");
```

Comment: These are the column headers for the data. I want to insert about 10,000 data points under these headers or attributes. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO. This is a SQL injection vulnerability, and allows people to execute arbitrary SQL on your database. What if $crash_year was set to `'; drop table nyccrash; --`? See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: **@hdgarrood** and you're suggesting to read a lection about database defence here? I suggest you to comment on an OP's question about it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar because this is exactly the wrong way to parameterise SQL queries from untrusted input.

Comment: @KalaJ If your data is text and datatype in database is `(varchar,text)` then you have to enclose the variables in `'`.

Comment: @CORRUPT What is a 'lection'? Yes, I absolutely am suggesting reading that site. Doing it properly is only marginally more effort.

Comment: @hdgarrood We can't parameterise SQL queries in `mysql_query`.

Comment: **@hdgarrood**, sorry, it was "lecture". But, still, you missing point. Your suggestion / notice / warning / whatever addressed wrong.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar If that's true, you should _never_ use it. As Till said in the comment on the question, you should use mysqli instead.

Comment: @hdgarrood If you are saying **this is exactly the wrong way to parameterise SQL queries from untrusted input.** then show to the OP the right way.

Comment: @hdgarrood If the question is asked for `mysql_query` then the answer will be in `mysql_query`, no one will write code in `mysqli` OR `PDO` for user. We can only advise him to stop using it.

Comment: **@Yogesh Suthar**, leave him. It's a pointless discussion (going nowhere) anyway, and inappropriate place for it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar done. And I disagree -- we should not answer questions with any `mysql_*` code, even if it is followed by a "don't use this" warning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parameterise SQL statements with untrusted input.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO nyccrash (crash_year, accident_type, 
  collision_type, weather_condition, light_condition, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) 
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $crash_year, ...);
$stmt->execute();
```

See http://codular.com/php-mysqli for more info on this.

If you don't understand why you should be doing it this way, look up SQL injection, and don't write another line of code until you do understand it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is trusted vs. untrusted input? This is interesting.

Comment: **@Kala J** He means _"input sanitizing is not an option"_, I think. The question about old ***mysql_**** functions (deprecated extension) against ***PDO_**** or ***mysqli_**** should be discussed on **[meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)** and not here, if my opinion matters.

Comment: Yay! It depends on whether it's come from you or from somebody else. For example, if it's a string literal in your source code, you can trust it. If it's from an HTTP POST submission from somewhere in the interwebs, you shouldn't trust it.

Comment: Having said that, I would always use bound parameters in database code. It's good practice -- for example, it protects you if a string which previously came from a trusted source starts coming from an untrusted one instead.

Comment: @CORRUPT meta is for questions and discussion about the site itself. mysql_* vs pdo or mysqli_* is definitely on topic for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the library of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125) answer

```
$csv    =   New CSVReader();
$result =   $csv->parse_file('Test.csv');//path to file should be csv
echo '<pre>';     //
print_R($result); // Only for testing

if($result){
    foreach($result as $row){
            $crash_year     =   $row['crash_year'];
            $accident_type      =   $row['accident_type'];
            $collision_type =   $row['collision_type'];
            $weather_condition  =   $row['weather_condition'];
            $light_condition    =   $row['light_condition'];
            $x_coordinate       =   $row['x_coordinate'];
            $y_coordinate       =   $row['y_coordinate'];

            $query  =   "INSERT INTO nyccrash";
            $query  .=  "(crash_year, accident_type, collision_type, weather_condition, light_condition, x_coordinate, y_coordinate)";
            $query  .=  " VALUES ";
            $query  .=  "('$crash_year','$accident_type','$collision_type', '$weather_condition', '$light_condition', '$x_coordinate', '$y_coordinate')";   
            mysqli_query($query);
            unset($query);
    }
}
```

One thing i noticed that in the insert query you must have some varchar fields in your database table and for that you are missing commas. Wrap the varchar fields with commas. This might be the problem and use die and mysql_error to see what the error really is.

Comment: Which and what CSVReader() class are you using?

Comment: click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125) for CSV Class CSVReader in the answer. include it in your page and use it.

Comment: deal it with yourself i have presented only a simple solution!

Comment: I am able to deal with it -- php newbies reading the question might not be