# Parse CSV content

Tags: php, parsing, csv

This must be relatively easy, but I'm struggling to find a solution.  I receive data using proprietary network protocol with encryption and at the end the entire received content ends up in a variable.  The content is actually that of a CSV file - and I need to parse this data.

If this were a regular file on disk, I could use `fgetcsv`; if I could somehow break the content into individual records, I could use `str_getcsv` - but how can I break this file into records?  Simple reading until a newline will not work, because CSV can contain values with line breaks in them.  Below is an example set of data:

```
ID,SLN,Name,Address,Contract no
123,102,Market 1a,"Main street, Watertown, MA, 02471",16
125,97,Sinthetics,"Another address,
Line 2
City, NY 10001",16
167,105,"Progress, ahead",,18
```

All of this data is held inside one variable - and I need to parse it.

Of course, I can always write this data into a temporary file on disk the read/parse it using `fgetcsv`, but it seems extremely inefficient to me.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125) is the answer. Use this library

Comment: @raheelshan Did you read the question?  That "library" reads from a file - and I don't have a file.  If I had a file, I wouldn't be asking this question, I know how to read CSV data from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fgetcsv` works for you, consider this:

```
file_put_contents("php://temp",$your_data_here);
$stream = fopen("php://temp","r");
// $result = fgetcsv($stream); ...
```

For more on `php://temp`, see [the php:// wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! One question: if I then do `file_put_contents` in `php://temp` the second time, will it overwrite the previously written content?

Comment: It should do, yes. I haven't actually used `php://temp` myself, but I would imagine it would work as if you were using a file called `php_temp` instead - you can read, write, append, overwrite...